# Comparing just the time component of two datetime64 columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am trying to subtract or compare **Only** the time component of two datetime64 columns but have been unsuccessful. I have tried using strftime with an exception block to catch NaTs but no luck. Any help is much appreciated. I have attached the Python code below.

```
Column A          Column B
1/1/1900 10:00      NaT
1/1/1900 10:30      NaT
1/1/1900 11:00      NaT
1/1/1900 9:00     2/6/2021 23:59
1/1/1900 11:00    2/6/2021 8:59
1/1/1900 9:30     2/6/2021 16:00

def convert(x):
    try:
        return x.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    except ValueError:
        return x

df['B'].apply(convert)-df['A'].apply(convert)
```

I get the error **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NaTType' and 'str'**

Answer (score 1):

Convert both columns to pandas `datetime` using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). Then extract just time using [`Series.dt.time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
df['Column A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column A'])
df['Column B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column B'])

In [213]: (df['Column A'] - df['Column B']).dt.components
Out[213]: 
      days  hours  minutes  seconds  milliseconds  microseconds  nanoseconds
0      NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN           NaN           NaN          NaN
1      NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN           NaN           NaN          NaN
2      NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN           NaN           NaN          NaN
3 -44232.0    9.0      1.0      0.0           0.0           0.0          0.0
4 -44231.0    2.0      1.0      0.0           0.0           0.0          0.0
5 -44232.0   17.0     30.0      0.0           0.0           0.0          0.0
```

From the above, you can extract `hours`, `minutes`, etc.. separately:

```
In [215]: (df['Column A'] - df['Column B']).dt.components.hours
Out[215]: 
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     9.0
4     2.0
5    17.0
Name: hours, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is not working, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time' in the last step   df['Column A'].dt.time - df['Column B'].dt.time